# Remove xfce without terminal access or default root account

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, desktop, xfce

I purged any packages related to xfce on Debian, and when I rebooted the login screen was still there. Upon login, there was only the wallpaper and a right click context menu available. Launching terminal emulator or Zutty closes them instantly. Tried booting into safe mode as well, makes no difference. How do I boot into a terminal or wipe xfce? Default root is disabled.

(sudo still works on one account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I boot into a terminal

Start with the kernel command-line option `rescue` (also known as `single` – the "single-user" mode). Debian uses GRUB, so press <kbd>e</kbd> at the boot menu to edit the kernel command line; add the option at the end of the 'linux' line.

If that doesn't work in some way, use the option `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to perform a normal boot but without the graphical login.

Other options: `emergency` (similar to 'rescue' but even smaller); `systemd.debug-shell` (normal boot but with a root terminal on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>).

> or wipe xfce?

Look through `dpkg -l` for the package corresponding to  "login screen" service (the display manager), which is *probably* LightDM but could also be GDM or SDDM – doing `systemctl list-dependencies graphical.target` should show the service name.

Once you've found the package, uninstall it with `sudo apt purge --autoremove`.

> Default root is disabled. (sudo still works on one account)

Anything you do as root, you can also do through 'sudo' (which literally lets you run things "as root").